# uiview animation does not call after navigating back from a viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, animation, ios6

I am Giving a uianimation with Infinite repeats in viewDidAppear: by code given below

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"theAnimation" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];

[UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:FLT_MAX];
[UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
[startButton setAlpha:.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];


[UIView commitAnimations];
[super viewDidAppear:YES];
```

but when I am navigating to some page with pushViewController and returning back to same view controller the viewDidAppear is calling but the animation is not working . and works fine when using presentViewController.Can please any one help me with it.
thanks

Comment: Try adding code in viewWillAppear.

Comment: no that also give same result

Answer (score 2):

Try to call `[super viewDidAppear:YES];` before animation code.

Comment: yes i try this not working and it is giving problem only in pushViewController not presentViewController

Comment: @chakshu http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UINavigationController/viewWillAppear.html